# Alphabetic analogue of Numero sign (№)?

Tags: lists, typography, ordinal-numbers

I'm typing up a spreadsheet that organises a television series's storyline, and the columns are supposed to be in the following format:

[image: Image1].

Is there an ordinal indicator I can put there where it says `[Ordinal]` that, rather than referring to *numeric* ordinals, actually refers to *alphabetic* ordinals?

After all, I'm sure I could still use the Numero sign, although a) it'd look weird in my opinion with letters instead of numerals, and b) I've already used it in Column A, so I'd prefer, if possible, to use another symbol altogether.

---

***EDIT***: When I find myself in this position, I typically use the Greek lowercase letter *Alpha* (α). However, I'm not entirely sure if this generally is used outside of my own personal documents.

Comment: Aren't they just 'labels'?

Comment: I don't think there's any widely understood/accepted symbol for that, so if you choose a symbol, whoever looks at your spreadsheet may not understand what you mean. The safest would be to just use something like "sequence", or the above commenter's "label". α isn't usually used in that way.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: Yes, *obviously*. But who uses that? It's much too generic.

Comment: @Yee-Lum: In this context, I personally think *sequence* would be more confusing than just using the Greek lowercase *alpha*. And, regarding its usage (or lack thereof, I suppose), yes, I figured as such.

Comment: I don't think labels on spreadsheets have any need to be _un_generic. They're meant to be easily understood by everyone at a glance. Depending on what the A, B, C, etc. actually stands for, I'm sure there's a better, simpler, more direct label you could use than "label", "sequence", or "α".

Comment: Yeah, but really? "Label"? That's just plain **too** generic, if you ask me.

Comment: Still, **this** spreadsheet can't use that. It won't do.

Comment: In any case, that's not the question. My question was whether one existed, not whether it should be used.